# Is there a spring 3.1 MVC annotation to turn off browser response caching?

Tags: http, spring-mvc, browser-cache

Is there some annotation in SpringMVC 3.1 to turn off browser caching on an MVC controller method?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/status")
public class StatusController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    //anyway to have an annotation here that turns of all the http caching headers?
    public String get()
    {
            // do some work here 
        return "status";
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of caching? Browser caching?

Comment: yes browser caching, in particular I want to send some headers without having to add a ServletRequestParamter to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there isn't an annotation, but there is a way to configure it via XML using an interceptor.  For example:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/status"/>
        <bean id="noCacheWebContentInterceptor"
                      class="com.nyx.spring.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: problem with this approach is that it is not maintainable because I would have to remember to change the interceptor settings if I change @RequestMapping in Spring.

Comment: @ams: That's why you should write tests, so you don't *need* to remember.